# Background image fixed and cover on mobile / tablet

Tags: css, responsive-design, tablet, smartphone

How do you get a fixed background image that scales to viewport to work correctly on smartphone / tablet?

Any of the [methods mentioned here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) do not work well with what I've tested (Galaxy Nexus & TF300t, using default browser, Firefox, or Chrome all have trouble with flashing / strange resizing, or ignoring the "cover" instruction)

The one thing I've come to see is to not put the background image on the HTML tag for touch devices, because they seems to scroll a full height viewport rather than scroll within the HTML tag.

```
body {
  background: black url("../img/cover.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  -moz-background-size: cover; 
  -o-background-size: cover; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: How do you get a fixed background image that scales to viewport to work correctly on smartphone / tablet?

Comment: What about an jQuery approach?

Comment: The jQuery approach outlined in the link above doesn't work properly either. When you change rotation the background image leaves a large white gap on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I've written some months ago an approach what fits your needs: http://plugins.jquery.com/fitpic/

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://ge.tt/api/1/files/1jN8IzR/0/blob?download" class='bg'>
```

**CSS**
*not really needed*

```
.bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1
}
```

**JS**

```
var fitPic = (function() {
    var winW = $(window).width(),
        winH = window.innerHeight || $(window).height(); // `innerHeight` for mobile safari

    $(".bg").each(function() {

        var elem = $(this),
            elemW = elem.width(),
            elemH = elem.height(),

            imgW = (elemW * winH) / elemH,
            imgH = (elemH * winW) / elemW,

            newW = imgH < winH ? imgW : winW,
            newH = imgH < winH ? winH : imgH;

        this.style.width = newW + "px";
        this.style.height = newH + "px";

    });
});

$(window).on('load resize', fitPic);
```